# BigQuery: How to add a new calculated column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I’m new to SQL so apologies if this is a basic question. I have a table in BigQuery that I’d like to add a new column to based on another.
The table has Column A with number values of FLOAT, I want to create Column B which will be False if Column A is less than 1.0 or True if it is greater. How exactly could I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [if](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#if):

```
IF(columnA < 1, False, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this

ALTER TABLE  BigQuery
ADD B varchar(10) NULL
CONSTRAINT df_BigQuery DEFAULT
(CASE WHEN A < 1.00 THEN 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' END)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below

```
select *, columnA < 1 as new_column
from your_table
```

Note: you do not need to use `IF ...` or `CASE ...` because `columnA < 1` by itself already returns either `true` or `false` (*with exception when columnA is null*)